# How to iterate over columns in CSV to find which one contains rows of dates in Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have several CSV files that I need to read through inside of python3 using Pandas. I am trying to find which column (or index) of each CSV contains a column with dates. Two caveats:

1. None of the CSV's have the same structure, some the dates column could be first, some it could be the second or third, and
2. The dates are always in a different format, sometimes they are like "Oct 28", othertimes they are "7/11", and anything in between.

I have already began iterating through them using Pandas like so, and I can pretty quickly identify if a column contains dates using the datetime parse function. Im having trouble going column by column (through each header to check for words like "date") as well as through each row in that column to see if I can parse it as a date. Ideas?

Example CSV:

```
Table
DATE ,TOPIC 
Aug 21 ,"Some text here"
Aug 23 ,Some other text here, it isn't always in quotes
```

Current code for iterating through the rows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filePath)

for i, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(), 0):
   print(i, row.Index)
```

Edit:
Here is my current code for iterating through each row in the Index column of a file. This works when the dates are in the index, but I need to loop through each column (not just the index) to see which one contains the dates.

```py
for i, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(), 0):
   for keyword in dateKeywords:
       if keyword.lower() in row.Index.lower():
           foundColumn = True

       if foundColumn:
           for days in dayAndMonthList: 
                if days in row.Index:
                     canParse = is_date(row.Index)
                     print(canParse)
```

The above code loops through the Dataframe, and looks for keywords like "date" or "week" to see a potential dates column. If it finds one, it then goes through to see if the rows in that column all contain the name (or abbreviation) of a month). This works to parse dates in the index column, but how can I make it shift over and test each column for the keyword, and then loop through the rows in that column to check if they're parseable?

Comment: So all you want to know are the names of columns that contain the dates, right?

Comment: I want to be able to find that column that contains dates, and then iterate over each row in that specific column to be able to do stuff with the information inside of that column/row.

Comment: IMO, trying to parse or recognize arbitrarily formatted dates is a *very* complicated problem and the time spent trying to accomplish that is often better spent making changes upstream to ensure dates are input and stored in a standard format. For all that `pandas` can do, it can still only recognize a small subset of standard ISO formatted dates without a user manually specifying the `format` parameter in `pd.to_datetime`. That should give you some pause...

Comment: Unfortunately the CSV file's coming in are from outside sources, and I have no way of going through and enforcing them to have a specific format. I will not that 95% of the time, it is m/d or mon/day (ex. 8/28). The year can be assumed to be the current year.

Comment: Okay, that's a bit more manageable then. Perhaps you could try specifying a bunch of formats to try and then try each format with `pd.to_datetime(... errors='coerce')`. You could choose a small susbet, maybe 100 -1000 rows, and consider it a `date` if any of those formats return more than 90% non-null dates? This could get more complicated if the same column could have dates in different formats.

Comment: Fortunately in my situation as well, if one date is in a specific format they are all in the same format. Also, most tables are usually 2-5 columns, and usually no more than 30-40 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving index/column pairs that refer to cells containing dates in a DataFrame:

```
# random setup
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.parser import parse
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "DATE": ['15/05/1965', '02/15/1994', 'Aug 23'],
    "MIX": ['ABC', 'DEF', '02/05/1995'],
    "TRICKERY": ['some chars', 'obfuscating 12/12/2000 the date', 'more chars'],
    "NAT": ['not', 'at', 'all']
})

# solution
def get_date(s):
    try:
        parse(s, fuzzy=True)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

# get a boolean dataframe with True values indicating a cell is a date
df = df.applymap(get_date)

# get a list of tuples containing an index and a column name
parsable = df[df].stack().index.tolist()

>>> df
   DATE    MIX    NAT  TRICKERY
0  True  False  False     False
1  True  False  False      True
2  True   True  False     False

>>> parsable
[(0, 'DATE'), (1, 'DATE'), (1, 'TRICKERY'), (2, 'DATE'), (2, 'MIX')]
```

Comment: This seems to point me that way. I actually already had a function to check that a date can be parsed. The weird thing is with the function you specified it parses them all as false, but if I parse them as objects (instead of strings) its able to parse them into dates. I can make an edit to the above with the code I am referring to.

Comment: That's odd, indeed. Please do.

Comment: Please see my edit above to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Is it helpful now?

Comment: Hi! I just checked it and it seems to be working but the problem is this: for some reason the dates get_dates function doesn't seem to be parsing the dates all correctly, saying about 3 out of 20 of them are True, and the rest are False (even though they all have the same format, etc). Any ideas?

Edit: With your value of df it works fine, but when I do `df = pd.read_csv(filePath)` where filePath is a csv file, it doesn't seem to recognize them all as dates (they are in the format Aug 23).

Comment: Nevermind, I seem to have fixed it! It seems to be working. For some reason, the opening of my CSV was opened with the word "Table". I think it was shifting the columns/rows off and messing it all up. Everything that is a date now gets parsed as one!